# interview question of hypothesis test: how many tests are needed to say a biased coin

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Here is an interview question of hypothesis test:

> When you observe 10% more heads than tail, how many times do you have to test to get the statistical significance to say coin is biased?

I don't much understand what I should test?

Does that mean we should test $H_0: p = 50\%,$ using number of head $X\sim N(np,np(1-p))?$ And calculate $n$ to make
$$\dfrac{55\%n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$$
match significant level? Here $55\% - 45\% = 10\%.$

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4250710/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom sorry I am not familiar with the policy. Is it allowed cross post? Since the question seems both related to math and statistics.